# calendar not retrieving localstorage data

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

Trying to set up an event calendar with support for offline view using localstorage (based on calendar at http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/)

I've managed to store all the data in my localstorage as below but when trying to load calendar offline, it fails to load. Any ideas? I need to get this complete asap :-)

JSON

```
$.getJSON("dates.json.php", function(data) {
                 calendar_items = data;
                 localStorage.setItem("calendar_items", JSON.stringify(calendar_items));

which stores...

[{"date":"2014-02-04 00:00:00","type":"event","title":"Test","url":"","id":"361"},{"date":"2014-02-05 00:00:00","type":"event","title":"Test 2","url":"","id":"361"},{"date":"2014-02-06 00:00:00","type":"event","title":"Test 3","url":"","id":"361"}]
```

CALENDAR (ONLINE)

```
$("#eventCalendarHumanDate").html();
$("#eventCalendarHumanDate").eventCalendar({
    eventsjson: "dates.json.php",
    jsonDateFormat: 'human'
});
```

CALENDAR (OFFLINE)

```
$("#eventCalendarHumanDate").html();
$("#eventCalendarHumanDate").eventCalendar({
    eventsjson: localStorage.getItem("calendar_items"),
    jsonDateFormat: 'human'
});
```

Unsure where to go from here. I have tried the following

(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("calendar_items"))) but this hasn't worked either.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, just look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Also, try to replace `eventsjson` with `jsonData` for your "offline mode" (`localStorage.getItem()` returns Object, not a file name)

Comment: noted and resolved in calendar online.  I edited the full path and removed chars by accident.  However, it is the offline code which I'm questioning :-)

Comment: Sorry n1k1ch I don't follow. If it's offline wouldn't I be looking for only the data items via localstorage and not a file name?

Comment: As i can see from plugin's page under **inline json** example, if you have raw json data and not a file name, you should sent this data to plugin via `jsonData` option. Your `localStorage.getItem('calendar_items')` will return raw json data

Comment: As i can see, under the hood, plugin loads json data, specified in `eventsjson`, by [$.getJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). This method receives an url (like `yourFile.json`). So, in your code, when using `eventsjson`, plugin is trying to use `[{"date":"2014-02-04 00......` url (value stored in `localStorage`)